# Dynamically change the font size in webbrowser in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, zooming, font-size

Could anyone please help me , how I can programmatically increase or decrease the font size of web browser control in windows phone 7 c sharp . I need this to implement the zoom functionality in web browser control.
here is my code

```
 private void btn_zoomin_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double fs = webBrowser1.FontSize;

        webBrowser1.FontSize = fs+10;
     }
```

But the font is not being changed at all.

Any kind of help will be appreciated. 
 Many thanks,
 Munazza

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's supposed to work this way.

The user can zoom in and out like he does in the Internet Explorer, but you can't change the font size.

You could, technically, get the html file that you want to display, parse it and if the fontsize is defined inline, you could change it and then display the new html file in the WebBrowser control, but I don't think that's a very good idea.

Comment: thanks, Could u plz tell me if mshtml.dll can be used in wp7 or not?

Comment: I would say no, but not 100% sure.

Comment: You may not be able to directly change the font size, but you can change the font size of a certain element (i.e., the body) by WebBrowser.InvokeScript. See my post below.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a solution, you  can fire a script inside the html page to enlarge the font by using the webBrowser's "InvokeScript" , here is a sample:

```
webBrowser1.InvokeScript("ChangeFontSize","12");
```

TO DO : a script inside the html :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function ChangeFontSize(size) {
            .....
            ....
            return true;
        }
<script/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use WebBrowser.InvokeScript:

```
// Initial text size
int textSize = 100;

private void TextPlusOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textSize *= 2;
    string szfn = "{styleText = \"body { -ms-text-size-adjust:" + textSize + "% }\";styleTextNode = document.createTextNode(styleText);styleNode = document.createElement(\"style\");styleNode.appendChild(styleTextNode);document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0].appendChild(styleNode);};";
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", szfn);
}

private void TextMinusOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textSize /= 2;
    string szfn = "{styleText = \"body { -ms-text-size-adjust:" + textSize + "% }\";styleTextNode = document.createTextNode(styleText);styleNode = document.createElement(\"style\");styleNode.appendChild(styleTextNode);document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0].appendChild(styleNode);};";
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("eval", szfn);
}
```

See [a description on the text size adjust property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-size-adjust) and [this post on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-us/abeb203d-eb6d-4297-8c93-6762b12036c6/font-size-not-setting-in-web-browser-control-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop).